# how to set masterpage dom element in contentpage with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dom, master-pages

a div in asp.net masterpage,i want hide it in one of its content page ,so I add this js at the end of content page

```
if (document.getElementById('sitemap'))
189 document.getElementById('sitemap').display = "none";
```

div sitemap in materpage, when i debug this js,document.getElementById('sitemap') run ok,but it can't be hiden .why? if I want set materpage's dom element style in content page,how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing the style-member:

```
document.getElementById('sitemap').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a .Net control(ASP:Panel), leave a hook in your Masterpage to access it, otherwise Dr.Molle's answer is what you need:

**Masterpage**:

```
function HideSiteMap()
{
   document.getElementById('" + sitemap.ClientID + "').style.display = "none";               
}
```

**Contentpage**:

Call the function.